# Detecting functions using stack trace

Tags: c++, debugging, stack-trace, symbols

I am looking at an application with a debugger (I don't have the source code!).
I put a breakpoint in a certain function (exported function) and I look at the stack trace.
Obviously I cannot see the symbols, but I can see the DLL name and an ordinal.

My question is how can I tell if the functions I see in the stack trace are exported ? or to be more accurate, Are the ordinals I see in the stack trace are the same ordinals I see in dependency walker?

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: POW: "State your name, platform and toolchain"?

Comment: Its a windows machine.
I don't quite understand what you mean by "name" and "toolchain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its a windows machine. I don't quite understand what you mean by "name" and "toolchain". – TCS

TCS: I was hinting at the fact that there is more than one debugger, and more than one linker that may generate different type of metadata in DLL's.

To the point, I've had good 'debugging' (inspecting/auditing) third-party software (including DLL's) with **[`OllyDbg`](http://www.ollydbg.de)**, of which there now seems to be a brand-new version 2.0 ([here](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html)).

It makes code analysis a whizz (if you know your way around assembly language and dynamic loading, I guess). It certainly makes easy work of tracking what module calss which and mapping those (calls) to symbolic names if available[1](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html). OllyDbg in particular is free.

On the commercial front, I believe there are several similar tools, of which I recall [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) to be the biggest name.

Hope that helps.

<sub>[1](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) It will leverage debug symbols (such as the ones you can download from Microsoft) and it will even translate arguments to Win32 APIs into their meaningful names (i.e. WM_PAINT instead of a constant, knowing the expected LPPARAM layout too etc).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The command `dumpbin \exports name.dll`, launched from a Visual Studio Command Prompt, will tell you all exported functions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
I know how to see the exported functions, but I don't know if the ordinals I see in the call stack are the same as in dependency walker.